# why is div width not showing actual width?

Tags: html

i want to create a div with width=5cm, but when i measure the div using a ruler on the screen, its not actually 5cm but less. what am i missing here, and how can i make the div width actual 5cm??

heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rg37tsp2/)

html

```
 <div class="c">This is some text.</div>
```

css

```
 div.c {
 border:1px solid black;
  width:5cm;
 }
```

Comment: `cm` is mostly used for printing

Comment: 1cm on screen shouldn't be 1cm in print. Use any _normal_ unit for screen, mm/cm for print only.

Comment: Use `px` or `em` or `rem`. I think it's standard.

Comment: @IbrahimHasnat: and vw/vh/% aren't standard? :-) What about ex/ch? vmin/vmax?

Comment: Excuse me for my non-relative question, but, what is `printing`?

Comment: @pavel My mistake. I wrote about mostly used units. Had not in my mind all of these lists at that time. :)

Comment: thank you all for the input. i am actually generating pdf pages using jspdf and thats why i need the width in cm units. im using html2pdf library, which creates a canvas screenshot using html2canvas. i need the div width in cm hence.

Comment: @matt2k12 print this PDF and measure the result on paper. 5cm should be really 5cm (on screen it can be different).